# Find all checked checkbox attribute value as xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

How do I find all checked checkbox's attribute value as an xml string?

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkDocId1" myattribute="myval1"/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkDocId2" myattribute="myval43"/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkDocId3" myattribute="myval21"/>
  ..
  ..
```

I want to find all checked checkboxes "myattribute" value as an xml string like below,

```
<selected>
  <idx>myval1</idx>
  <idx>myval143</idx>
 ..
 ..
</selected>
```

What's the best way to do it? I'm using ASP.net and HTML. Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like following.

```js
var xml = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return '<idx>' + $(this).attr('myattribute') + '</idx>';
}).get().join('');

xml = '<selected>' + xml + '</selected>';

console.log(xml)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked id="chkDocId1" myattribute="myval1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkDocId2" myattribute="myval43"/>
<input type="checkbox" checked id="chkDocId3" myattribute="myval21"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can do something like this.

```js
// generate the parent element using jQuery and
// cache it for reference
var $sel = $('<selected/>');

// get all checkbox which has attribute `myattribute`
$(':checkbox[myattribute]').each(function() {
  // generate `idx` element with the content
  $('<idx/>', {
    html: $(this).attr('myattribute')
      // append element to parent
  }).appendTo($sel);
});

// get markup of the element fro object
console.log($sel[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkDocId1" myattribute="myval1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkDocId2" myattribute="myval43" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkDocId3" myattribute="myval21" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood you correctly, correct me if I'm wrong. So what I did is loop through every checkbox, got the custom `myattribute` values and appended them to an array using xml tags:

```js
var xmlArr = [];
xmlArr += "<selected>";
//to loop only through checked checkboxes just replace $('input[type="checkbox"]') with $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
  var myAttribute = $(this).attr('myattribute');
  xmlArr += "<idx>" + myAttribute + "</idx>"; 
});
xmlArr += "<selected>";
console.log(xmlArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkDocId1" myattribute="myval1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkDocId2" myattribute="myval43" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkDocId3" myattribute="myval21" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the xml structure by *looping* through the checkboxes - it is also recommended to use `data-` for custom attributes and access it using `.data()` method.

See demo below:

```js
var xml = $('<selected></selected>');
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
  xml.append('<idx>' + $(this).data('myattribute') + '</idx>');
});

$('#result').append(xml);
console.log(xml[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkDocId1" data-myattribute="myval1"/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkDocId2" data-myattribute="myval43"/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkDocId3" data-myattribute="myval21"/>

<br/>
<div id="result"></div>
```